# Pure JS multi-slide carousel

Tags: javascript, image, dom

On our home page we need simple multi-slide carousel. It is our highest traffic page, so we decided to remove all libraries (including jQuery) in order to increase page speed.

Functionality we trying to achieve is similar to [this](https://puu.sh/xOhCN/97f601f55f.mp4)

Here is the code we have now: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gety9/pen/MEvMZO)

```js
function getStyleValue(elem, property) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue(property);
}

const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel .arrow"),
  [leftArrow, rightArrow] = arrows,
  slideContainer = document.querySelector(".carousel .slide-container"),
  slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide"),
  amt = parseInt(getStyleValue(slides[0], "width"));

try {
  let trans = parseInt(
    getStyleValue(slideContainer, "transform")
      .split(",")[4]
      .trim()
  );
} catch (e) {
  console.log("`trans` being set to 0");
  trans = 0;
}

function slide() {
  if (this === rightArrow) {
    trans -= amt;
  } else if (this === leftArrow) {
    trans += amt;
  }
  if (trans <= amt * slides.length / 2 * -1) {
    rightArrow.style.display = "none";
  } else if (trans >= 0) {
    leftArrow.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    arrows.forEach(arrow => (arrow.style.display = "inline-block"));
  }
  slideContainer.style.transform = `translate(${trans}px)`;
}

arrows.forEach(arrow => arrow.addEventListener("click", slide));
```

```css
body *::selection {
  background: none;
}

.carousel {
  --height: 128px;
  --width: 120px;
  display: block;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  height: var(--height);
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel * {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.arrow-container {
  --width-arrow: 64px;
  width: var(--width-arrow);
}

.arrow {
  --arrow-width: calc(var(--width-arrow) / 2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: var(--arrow-width);
  height: var(--arrow-width);
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: var(--arrow-width);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transition: background-color 111ms, color 222ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white;
}

.arrow:active {
  transform: scale(0.9) translate(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.arrow.left {
  display: none;
}

.display-container {
  /* * 4 to show 4 slides */
  width: calc(var(--width) * 4 - 2px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide-container {
  /* * 8 cause that's the number of slides */
  width: calc(var(--width) * 8);
  /* start by going left 2 slides */
  /* transform: translate(calc(var(--width) * -2)); */
  transition: transform 333ms;
}

.slide {
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: var(--width);
  background-color: salmon;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="arrow-container">
    <span class="arrow left">&lt;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="display-container">
    <div class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">1</div>
      <div class="slide">2</div>
      <div class="slide">3</div>
      <div class="slide">4</div>
      <div class="slide">5</div>
      <div class="slide">6</div>
      <div class="slide">7</div>
      <div class="slide">8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-container">
    <span class="arrow right">&gt;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Minor issues

- Don't use `window.` inconsistently. You use it in some places and then not in others. It's just noise so the best option is that if you find yourself typing `window.blah` you have added 7 needless characters.
- Don't use compound declarations, they can be a source of hard to spot errors, especially as you are not using strict mode.
- "use strict" Never release code that does not use strict mode, and it must have used strict mode from day one.
- Avoid using `parseInt` unless you define the radix, eg parseInt("16",10). Better way to parse a string to a number is via `Number(string)`. Or a safer form `const number = isNaN(str) ? defaultNumber : Number(str);`
- Your slide function at first tests for both the left and right arrow. but if the only events that will generate the call are the two arrows the second statement should be else and not include the redundant if statement.
- Don't do complex expressions inside conditional statements. Generally conditional statement should be limited to the test. You had `if (trans <= amt * slides.length / 2 * -1) {` would be better split as two lines; `const pos =amt * slides.length / 2 * -1;` then `if(trans <= pos) {`

#### Bad code.

There are some that will not agree, this is an opinion on good coding practice for JavaScript.

The code in question

> ```
> try {
>   let trans = parseInt(
>     getStyleValue(slideContainer, "transform")
>       .split(",")[4]
>       .trim()
>   );
> } catch (e) {
>   console.log("`trans` being set to 0");
>   trans = 0;
> }
> ```

There are very few situations in `javascript` when you need to use a `try` `catch` block.  I feel that if you are using them you are being lazy.

There are many problems that can be overlooked when using try catch. Here are just 3 for your case.

1. You catch all errors, not just the one you have planned for. Code running in the catch should **always** check the error and only handle the one you intend to handle, all other errors should be thrown to a higher level.

   As you have it you will consume all errors, errors that could cause problems later in your code but will not know about till way after it first threw an error.
2. You are forcing the error via the `trim` function `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined` this is no guarantee of the problem being caught.

   I was at first puzzled as to why the `trim` was there as `parseInt` will do it for you, till it dawned on me, to throw the (incorrect) error.

   So not only badly using the try catch you are not using a standard method to throw a known error. You should have used `throw` and thrown a `new Error("blah blah");` (I put "blah blah" because I do not consider it an error at all and have no words to describe it.)
3. **Major scope problem** You will never get the correct result as `trans` is declared as scoped to the try block and the `catch` if invoked assigns to a new global scope `trans`.

   The only value `trans` will have after that code has run is as an undefined undeclared variable (Very dangerous) or as the global scoped `trans = 0;`

It does not take much effort to avoid the try catch, and in this case the  cluster of problems it has set up in your code.

#### Quick rewrite.

I did not look at variable naming, function design and layout, and other issues as It was the try catch the got my attention.

Thus all I did was rewrite the try catch block as a function returning transform property or zero. If you run it here as snippet, it will throw for a very different reason though.

```js
function getTrans(element){
  var value = getStyleValue(element, "transform");
  value = value.split(",")[4];
  if(value !== undefined){
    return Number(value);
  }
  return 0;
}
var trans = getTrans(slideContainer);
```